# Cannot delete resource from Database using jersey

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, restful-architecture

I am a beginner, trying to implement a simple CRUD application using jersey. I am trying to delete one row based on the input passed by the user through a web page. But my method is not being called i am getting the following error.

```
HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed

type Status report

message Method Not Allowed

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

This following is my delete function which should delete based on the FormParam it gets through html.

```
      @DELETE
      @Path("/delete")
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      public void delEmployeeFormParam(@FormParam("Employee_id") int employee_id){

            java.net.URI location= null;
            System.out.println("teting");
            try 
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Employee_db", "root", "root");

                String query = "delete from employee where emp_id = (?)";

                PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query);
                st.setInt(1, employee_id);
                st.executeQuery();

            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

      }
```

The html code is shown below.

```
<body>
    <h3> Enter Employee Id to Delete </h3>

    <div>
        <form method="DELETE" action="http://localhost:8080/RESTCRUD/rest/employee/delete">
            <p>Employee Id: <input type:"text" name="Employee_id"/></p>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

One thing to Note other methods such as GET and POST are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think HTML forms support DELETE (only GET and POST).  See this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers) for more details.

> HTML forms (up to HTML version 4 and XHTML 1) only support GET and
>   POST as HTTP request methods.

Comment: For debugging you can do a couple of things.  You can use a command line tool like `curl` or a browser REST API calling extension to test out the DELETE and confirm the server is configured correctly.  You could also attach a proxy or log the request parameters to see what is really getting passed by the browser.